# SQL Server - Running Count of specific values in a column

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to create a data set for analysis that incorporates daily transactions as well as days when no transaction has been made.

[image]

The ideal result would be the same as the Count(subsequent 0's) column. I have tried doing running totals but have not found a way to count only rows with a '0' in the transactions column and then resetting the count when the transactions column is <> 0.

Thanks

Comment: `,isnull(sum(isnull(transactions,0)) over ( partition by accountnumber order by cal.CalendarDate rows between 90 preceding and current row),0)  as Previous90DaySubmission`

Comment: `,count(rows) over (partition by transactions = 0 order by calendardate) as NoTransactionCount`

Comment: two different ways that I still have on my screen of trying to calculate the 'running subsequent ) column'

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem in SQL Server 2016 SP1 (13.0.4001.0). This looks like a "Gaps and Islands in Sequences" problem and my solution is a modification of one of the examples by [Dwain Camps](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/).

**NOTE**: The original example lists a single account number, but the solution caters for multiple account numbers.

```sql
with TestData as
(
    -- data for Mr Bill Withers (account number 11300)
    select CONVERT(date, '29/06/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 1 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '30/06/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 3 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '01/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 2 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '02/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '03/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '04/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 4 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '05/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 3 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '06/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '07/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '08/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '09/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '10/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11300 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bill Withers' as AccountName, 1 as Transactions

    union

    -- data for Mr Bob Builder (account number 11301)
    select CONVERT(date, '29/06/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11301 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bob Builder' as AccountName, 1 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '30/06/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11301 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bob Builder' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions
    union
    select CONVERT(date, '01/07/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11301 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Bob Builder' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions

    union

    -- data for Mr Ted Teddy (account number 11302)
    select CONVERT(date, '29/06/2016', 103) as CalendarDate, 11302 as AccountNumber, 'Mr Ted Teddy' as AccountName, 0 as Transactions

    -- add data for additional account numbers...
),

StartingPoints as
(
    select AccountNumber, CalendarDate, Transactions,
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by AccountNumber order by CalendarDate) as rownum
    from TestData as A
    where not exists (
        select *
        from TestData as B
        where B.AccountNumber = A.AccountNumber and Transactions = 0 and dateadd(day, 1, B.CalendarDate) = A.CalendarDate
    )
    and Transactions = 0
),

EndingPoints as
(
    select AccountNumber, CalendarDate, Transactions,
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by AccountNumber order by CalendarDate) as RowNum
    from TestData as A
    where not exists (
        select *
        from TestData as B
        where B.AccountNumber = A.AccountNumber and Transactions = 0 and dateadd(day, -1, B.CalendarDate) = A.CalendarDate
    )
    and Transactions = 0
),

ZeroTransactionRanges as
(
    SELECT S.AccountNumber, S.CalendarDate AS start_range, E.CalendarDate AS end_range
    FROM StartingPoints AS S
    INNER JOIN EndingPoints AS E ON E.AccountNumber = S.AccountNumber AND E.RowNum = S.RowNum
),

ZeroRunLengths as
(
    select CalendarDate,
           t1.AccountNumber,
           datediff(day, start_range, CalendarDate) + 1 as runLength
    from ZeroTransactionRanges as t1
    INNER JOIN TestData as t2
    on t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber
    where start_range <= t2.CalendarDate and t2.CalendarDate <= end_range
)

select t1.*,
       case when t2.runLength is null then 0 else t2.runLength end as 'Count(Subsequent 0s)'
from TestData as t1
-- note the LEFT join here!
LEFT JOIN ZeroRunLengths as t2
on t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber and t1.CalendarDate = t2.CalendarDate
order by AccountNumber, CalendarDate
```